# マルチスレッドで配列の和を取りたい

Tags: rust

以下の内容をお聞きしたいです。

### 背景

マルチスレッドについて少し触ったので配列を分割して和を、各スレッドで取得できるようにしようと考えました。

そこで以下のコードを作成しました。

- main.rs([playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=b2eb0c31cbc92a2c3413aed9c138ebd9))

```rust
use rand::prelude::*;
use std::thread;
use std::sync::Arc;
use std::sync::atomic::{AtomicUsize, Ordering};

fn main() {
    const N: usize = 10;
    const SIZE: usize = 10000000;
    let mut tasks = vec![];

    println!("[make array]");
    let arr = create_rand_array(SIZE);
    let result = Arc::new(AtomicUsize::new(0));
    for i in 0..N - 1 {
        let picked_arr = pick_array(i * N, SIZE / N, &arr);
        let result = Arc::clone(&result);
        let handle = thread::spawn(move || {
            result.fetch_add(sum(picked_arr), Ordering::SeqCst);
        });
        tasks.push(handle);
    }

    for task in tasks {
        task.join().unwrap();
    }

    println!("sum: {:?}", result);
}

fn sum(arr: &[usize]) -> usize {
    let mut result: usize = 0;
    arr.iter().for_each(|num| {
        result += num
    });
    result
}

fn create_rand_array(num: usize) -> Vec<usize> {
    let mut arr: Vec<usize> = Vec::with_capacity(num);
    let mut rng = rand::thread_rng();
    (1..num).for_each(|_| {
        arr.push(rng.gen::<usize>() % 1000);
    });
    arr
}

fn pick_array(start: usize, num: usize, arr: &[usize]) -> &[usize] {
    if start >= 0 && start + num < arr.len() {
        &arr[start..start + num - 1]
    } else {
        panic!("Invalid Args: start -> {}, num -> {}, arr.len() -> {}", start, num, arr.len());
    }
}
```

このコードを実行したところ

```
   Compiling playground v0.0.1 (/playground)
error[E0597]: `arr` does not live long enough
  --> src/main.rs:15:54
   |
15 |         let picked_arr = pick_array(i * N, SIZE / N, &arr);
   |                          ----------------------------^^^^-
   |                          |                           |
   |                          |                           borrowed value does not live long enough
   |                          argument requires that `arr` is borrowed for `'static`
...
28 | }
   | - `arr` dropped here while still borrowed
```

となりました。

自分としては

```rust
for task in tasks {
    task.join().unwrap();
}
```

があるから`arr`の参照である`picked_arr`がdropされるまで(`thread::spawn`のクロージャを抜けるまで)、`arr`は存在できるのではないかと考えています。

### お聞きしたいこと

- このコンパイルエラーを解消する方法をお聞きしたいです

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`thread::spawn`で生成したスレッドに変数をムーブ（所有権を移動）するには、その変数が `'static` ライフタイムを持っている必要があります。生成されたスレッドの処理は、おおもとのプロセスが終了する（メインスレッドが終了する）まではどこまでも続く可能性があるからです。

`pick_array`関数のライフタイムを明示的に書くと次のようになり、質問にある通り`picked_arr` と`&arr` のライフタイムは等しくなります。

```rust
fn pick_array<'a>(start: usize, num: usize, arr: &'a [usize]) -> 
 &'a [usize] {
```

ここでは`picked_arr`がスレッドにムーブされているので `'static` が必要になり、`pick_array`の定義によりライフタイムが伝搬されたため `&arr` にも `'static` が要求されている、ということになります。

とりあえずコンパイルが通るようにするには、`pick_array`から`Vec<usize>`を返すようにする方法があります（[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=d7c43ce9c8f401d09eb14fc020013538)）。効率の良い方法ではありませんが…

```rust
fn pick_array(start: usize, num: usize, arr: &[usize]) -> Vec<usize> {
    if start >= 0 && start + num < arr.len() {
        arr[start..start + num - 1].into()
```

また、`pick_array`のようにスライスの要素をまとめて取ってくるには、[`chunks`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.slice.html#method.chunks)が便利です。他にも[`fold`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.fold)や[`map`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.map)を使って書き換えると次のようになります。こちらでは[`Box::leak`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/boxed/struct.Box.html#method.leak)を使って `'static` ライフタイムを持つ参照を生成しています。

```rust
use rand::prelude::*;
use std::thread::{self, JoinHandle};
use std::sync::Arc;
use std::sync::atomic::{AtomicUsize, Ordering};

fn main() {
    const N: usize = 10;
    const SIZE: usize = 1000;

    println!("[make array]");
    let result = Arc::new(AtomicUsize::new(0));
    let arr = Box::new(create_rand_array(SIZE));
    let arr = Box::leak(arr);
    arr.chunks(N).map(|chunk| {
        let result = Arc::clone(&result);
        thread::spawn(move || {
            let sum = chunk.iter().fold(0, |sum, num| sum + *num);
            result.fetch_add(sum, Ordering::SeqCst);
        })
    })
　　 .collect::<Vec<JoinHandle<()>>>().into_iter()
    .for_each(|handle| handle.join().unwrap());

    println!("sum: {:?}", result);
}

fn create_rand_array(num: usize) -> Vec<usize> {
    let mut rng = rand::thread_rng();
    (1..num).map(|_| rng.gen::<usize>() % 1000).collect()
}
```

コメントの指摘にある通り、`collect`を呼ばないとイテレータが[遅延評価](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/index.html#laziness)されるため、それぞれのスレッドが`spawn`された後にすぐ`join`されてしまいます（比較: [Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=cd43e7f351ce4dd460b8dff9f0590a8b)）。

ちなみに、以前は `thread::scoped`という「スコープ付きスレッド」のようなものがあり、`'static`ではない参照を使えたのですが、いろいろとややこしい問題があり廃止されました（下記リンクを参照）。現時点では[crossbeam](https://docs.rs/crossbeam/0.8.1/crossbeam/fn.scope.html), [thread-scoped](https://github.com/arcnmx/thread-scoped-rs)クレートから同等の機能を使えます。*2022/8/31更新：Rust 1.63.0でスコープ付きスレッド [`std::thread::scope`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/thread/fn.scope.html) が復活しました。*

参考リンク

- [std::thread::JoinGuard (and scoped) are unsound because of reference cycles · Issue #24292 · rust-lang/rust](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/24292)
- [Threads and Lifetimes : rust](https://www.reddit.com/r/rust/comments/8epwbe/threads_and_lifetimes/)
- [Lifetime elision - The Rust Reference](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/lifetime-elision.html) (`substr2` の例に該当）

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます。`Box::leak`や`chunk`を知らなかったので、勉強になりました。1点お聞きしたいのですが、提示いただいたプログラムだとforeachでjoinしているから、`mapでspawn→join→mapでspawn→join...`という結局シリアルな処理になってしまうのかと思ったのですが、どうでしょうか？実行時間を測ったところ、分割しないでfoldした方が100倍程度早くなっていました。

Comment: 上記ですがchunk_sizeを`SIZE/N`にして、foreachではtasksにpushしその後join()を呼び出すとやったら、早くなりました。お騒がせしましたmm

Comment: 連続ですみません。`SIZE=100000000, N=10`までは上記の対処した方が早かったのですが、`SIZE=1000000000, N=10`になったら`arr.chunk.for_each`内でjoinした方が早くなりました。`arr.chunk.for_each`内でjoinした場合([Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=ca119013ddbb2898f5ea5ee70debb189))と、`arr.chunk.for_each`内ではtasksにpushして後からtasksのfor文内でjoinした場合([Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=a018b1f0992e286f8f0094a171523431))の挙動の違いを教えていただけたらと思います。

Comment: そうですね。上記の状態では遅延評価のおかげで並行処理ができていませんね。回答を修正します。`SIZE/N` を使うとプログラムの意味が変わってしまうので、それで速くなるのは関係ない気がします。

Comment: `tasks`というあらかじめ生成された `Vec` に `push()` する場合には、`tasks` 用のメモリ領域が必要です。一方、`collect()` を使って一旦 `Vec` にまとめる場合は内部で [`FromIterator::from_iter()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.FromIterator.html) が呼び出されます（イテレータから`Vec`にする関数）。`Vec` の [`from_iter()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/src/alloc/vec/mod.rs.html#2514) の実装はイテレータが持っていた領域を[なるべく使い回す](https://doc.rust-lang.org/src/alloc/vec/spec_from_iter.rs.html#39)ようになっていて、メモリを節約できます。Vecの内部実装には詳しくないので解釈には自信がありませんが…

Comment: また、この実装では `SIZE/N` 個のスレッドを生成します。条件によってはスレッド数が多すぎて、逆に遅くなります（比較用のPlaygroundを回答に追記しました）。

Comment: 色々と書き方から仕様まで知らないことが多く勉強になりました。上記内容で質問事項が終わったので解決としたいと思います。ご回答ありがとうございましたmm